# Java web service not display @XmlRootElement

Tags: java, service, web, jax-ws

this is my simple web service in Java:

```
@WebService
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customers")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customers{

    @WebMethod
        @XmlElement(name="Customer")
    public String getCustomer() 
        { 
        return "Jack"; 
    } 
}
```

it is deployed on Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (build 5) server.

SOAP client is write on PHP, and when I try using -

```
print_r($client->__getLastResponse());
```

I received following response:

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body><ns2:getCustomerResponse xmlns:ns2="http://zch/">
<Customer>Jack</Customer>
</ns2:getCustomerResponse ></S:Body></S:Envelope>`

there is not appear root element which I created by `@XmlRootElement(name = "Customers")`.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Just a guess but as your access type is FIELD but you do not have any fields

Comment: how can I declare FIELD?

Comment: The return Type of your WebMethod is String. Hence why would you expect the output to be a Customers object?

Comment: I need create root element. I studying creating web services now. And this is interested for me - creating structured (XML) response from web service with elements, subelements and etc.